# Is it possible to write/modify email draft with Qt?

Tags: qt

Is it possible to append text to email draft and save it using Qt ? No email sending is involved here, just accessing email draft, modify it and save it.

If so, what libraries/tools are required to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which email protocol you're interested in, but it doesn't really matter -- Qt has no built-in support for IMAP, MS Exchange, etc.

That said, Qt does include [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) and [QSslSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html). In theory you could implement whichever email protocol(s) you're interested in on top of these TCP socket implementations.

But implementing these protocols is a very significant amount of work and tricky to get right. I can't personally speak to Exchange, but IMAP has several distinct versions and various optional features that some servers support and others don't.

Then there's the issue of the email format itself. As far as I'm aware Qt doesn't include a MIME parser (let me know if I'm wrong about this in the comments.) Parsing MIME is only half the story, because after editing the draft you'll have to create a new MIME document to upload to the server.

After you've figured all of that out you still need to build a user interface that lets you edit the email. Most likely you want to edit HTML-based email, which means you probably want to integrate [QtWebEngine](https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine) and either build your own editor in Javascript or use an existing one.

If I were you I'd recommend using external libraries for whatever email protocol(s) you intend to support as well as dealing with MIME data. Recommending external libraries is off topic for Stack Overflow, but I'm sure you can find one on the web.

Comment: It is not about sending/receiving emails.

Comment: @SebastianLange Nothing I said applies to sending email -- implementing SMTP is a whole different can of worms.

Comment: Sorry I may misread some in a hurry. I was only about local file access not remote stored drafts.

Comment: hmm it sounds a lot intense than I imagined. I thought it wouldnt involve protocols if there isn't email sending involved. I guess I will have to resort to eternal libraries as suggested.